# Developing apps for Android using Html5, will restrict to access local disk, and other systems call?

Tags: android, html, google-app-engine, android-intent

While developing apps for Android using Html5. What are the restrictions that Html5 wont allow? For example my apps requirements are using local storage, copy paste files, opening socket, changing Android configurations for theme, and run the apps as daemon.

With Html5 will it be possible or i should skip using Html5 and go with other method?

Comment: Running the apps as daemons? What does your app do exactly? On Android, you could just write your app partially with Phone Gap/HTML5 and partially in Java. Personally, I would do everything in Java, but that's just me. You may prefer to mix and match yourself (for the parts that can't easily be done in HTML5, like launching Services or registering BroadcastReceivers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android doesn't natively support HTML5 apps.  You're going to have a Java app that contains a WebView in which your HTML5 UI exists.

You can communicate between the Javascript inside the webview and the Java app on the outside with a couple of hooks.  It's hacky, but you can always communicate out to the Java app and have the Java app implement the functionality you need.

Depending on how much work you're doing in HTML5 vs in Java, it may or may not be worth the hassle.  Generally the Java UI will be much smoother.